# Getting previous session using angular-devise

Tags: angularjs, devise

I'm trying to get a valid response from angular-devise using Auth.currentUser()

Per the documentation at: https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise

I'm executing:

```
  Auth.currentUser().then(function (user) {
    // User was logged in, or Devise returned
    // previously authenticated session.
    console.log('Auth', user);
    console.log('isAuth', Auth.isAuthenticated()); // => false
  }, function (error) {
    // unauthenticated error
    console.log('Autherror', error)
    console.log('isAuth', Auth.isAuthenticated()); // => false
  });
```

This results in a 401 Unauthorized call to login.json

In my config, I've set:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

I did notice that in the http request, the payload has an empty user object:

```
{"user":{}}
```

Context: I have pathways in my application that successfully allow new user registration. When a user enters through registration, Auth.currentUser() returns a valid object but does not make an api call:

```
Auth Object {id: 98, email: "casey@tom.com", first_name: "tom", last_name: "casey", created_at: "2014-12-04T19:55:40.981Z"…}
create.js?body=1:10 isAuth true
```